# Converting self-defined type to a string

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a function `goPosition` to convert my custom data type : `Position` into a `String`. Although I think I'm making sense, the compiler disagrees with me.

My datatype is:

```
data Position = Pos Char Int
```

My input is:

```
goPosition (Pos ('H' 3))
```

And the compiler returns :

```
<interactive>:6:15:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Position’
                with actual type ‘Int -> Position’
    Probable cause: ‘Pos’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the first argument of ‘goPosition’, namely ‘(Pos ('H' 3))’
    In the expression: goPosition (Pos ('H' 3))

<interactive>:6:20:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> Char’
                with actual type ‘Char’
    The function ‘'H'’ is applied to one argument,
    but its type ‘Char’ has none
    In the first argument of ‘Pos’, namely ‘('H' 3)’
    In the first argument of ‘goPosition’, namely ‘(Pos ('H' 3))’
```

Maybe it's my problem that I had given an incorrect input? I'm really not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `f x y z` calls `f` with three arguments. `f (x y z)` calls function `x` with two arguments (`y` and `z`) and then call `f` with the result of that. Hence the error in `Pos ('H' 3)` and the GHC message "The function H is applied to one argument".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I got the input wrong. Should be goPosition (Pos 'H' 3)

Comment: If you no longer need an answer, you can delete the question by using the delete link provided below the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That... seems like odd advice, given the way this site is set up. It seems like taking that reasoning to its logical conclusion, every successful question (i.e. that got an answer that worked for the querent) would get deleted!

Comment: @DanielWagner: The problem was a typo.  There's a specific close reason for that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think so. A typo is when you type something you didn't intend. It's incredibly unlikely that somebody else has the same intention as you *and* makes the same typing mistake, so corrections to that don't generalize. But this person typed what they intended -- they just intended the wrong thing, and I think others could reasonably have the same wrong intention and get value out of seeing why their intention was wrong. (In fact I'd be shocked if this were the very first question on SO about this exact mistake!)

Comment: And this is where I say "Discussions like this are what the Meta site is for."